# Change source in Audio MIDI Setup via command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, audio, airplay

Is there a way to change the AirPlay source in **Audio MIDI Setup** via the command line (currently I'm doing this with GUI scripting)? My idea is to change the source with the **defaults** command in the application's .plist-file, but I've not been able to find the correct file/value.

I've found and looked in the following files, but nothing there reflects the AirPlay source:

***/Users/Name/Library/Preferences/com.apple.audio.AudioMIDISetup.plist /Users/Name/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.MIDI.xxxxxx.plist /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist***

Does anyone know where the Audio MIDI Setup application store it's preferences, and if it's possible to change them via the command line?

[image: Audio MIDI Setup]

**Update:** With **fs_usage** I've found that the only file that's called (by **coreaudiod**) when changing AirPort device (both in Audio MIDI setup and in the Sound preference pane) is ***/Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist*** - however, that file does not exist(?).

```
10:55:29.548583  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000070   coreaudiod.6108520
10:55:29.548621  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000036   coreaudiod.6108520
10:55:29.548657  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000034   coreaudiod.6108520
10:55:29.548692  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000034   coreaudiod.6108520
10:55:29.548727  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000034   coreaudiod.6108520
10:55:29.548762  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000034   coreaudiod.6108520
10:55:29.551067  read              F=4    B=0x20                                                                                                                                                                              0.000024   coreaudiod.6152896
10:55:29.557136  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000069   coreaudiod.6108520
10:55:29.557338  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000045   coreaudiod.6108520
10:55:29.557455  stat64                                 /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist                                                                                                       0.000041   coreaudiod.6108520
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, check this thread on Apple forum: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3554173?tstart=0

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that solution only lets me change the output _device_ (From Built-in Output to AirPlay to external DAC etc.) - I need to specify the AirPlay _source_ (I have multiple AirPlay devices), that can only be done in the Audio MIDI Setup application, not in the Sound Pref pane.